# An exercise of Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

That's the original question:

> Let $M$ be a compact manifold without boundary and $U \subset M$ be an open set. Assume that $f: M \rightarrow M$ has $f(M) \subset U$. Using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, prove that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$,
> $$
> \operatorname{tr}\left(f^*: H^k(M) \rightarrow H^k(M)\right)=\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(\left.f\right|_U\right)^*: H^k(U) \rightarrow H^k(U)\right)
> $$
> where the trace is for the matrix corresponding to the linear mapping.

There seems to be an oversight here, so we also need to assume that $H^*(U)$ is a finite dimensional space.

I guess the professor wants us to use homomorphism between long exact sequence to solve this problem. I think I should use $f$ on a long exact sequence, and then use some knowledge of homology algebra to get the conclusion.

My question is how do I use Mayer-Vietoris sequence to prove this? I don't know how to construct a open cover.

Comment: How have you started to set up Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: How do you view $H^k(U)$ as a subspace of $H^k(M)$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin My current idea is to construct an open cover from $U$ or $f(M)$, but I don't know what to do and whether it's correct.

Comment: @Daniel I think the closed form or exact form in $\Omega^k(U)$ is also the closed form or exact form in $\Omega^k(M)$, which seems to explain $H^k(U)$  is a subspace of $H^k(M)$.

Comment: Yes, you should use $U$. Now, how do you create an open set $V$ so that the union is $M$? How might you use $f(M)$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I plan to find a open ball $B$ in $U$ and let $V=M-B$. 
The idea of using $f(M)$ to construct open covers stems from that my M-V sequence seems to need $f$, but I don't know how to use the map.

Comment: Think more seriously about my last question. You should also understand that $H^k(U)$ is *not* in general  a subspace of $H^k(M)$.

Comment: I wanted to add that even if $H^\ast(U)$ *was* a subspace of $H^\ast(M)$, the trace formula doesn't follow.  E.g, the identity map $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ has trace $2$, but when restrcted to a line, the trace is $1$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito It was my carelessness. You are right. I've modified the problem description.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Compact manifold has a finite good cover, then its cohomology is finite dimensional.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm sorry. I mistook $U$ for $f(M)$. There is really a problem here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know why do you need to use Mayer-Vietoris. You have maps
$$
g:M \to U \quad i :U \to M
$$
so $f=i \circ g$, $f_{\mid U}=g \circ i$, and so $f^* = g^*\circ i^*$ and $f_{\mid U}^* = i^* \circ g^*$. Then this just boils down to the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$

Comment: I guess the professor wants us to use homomorphism between long  exact sequence for exercise, but that was a very clever answer. Thank you a lot!